# Filter rows together refer to value in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code .. it is working fine ., but I need to move row with value "closed" in column K to be after last row with same text, also when add "x" to column if should move after last row with "x" value.
Any suggestion please ..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim rw As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
rw = Target.Row

If rw = 2 Then
      'Do nothing
Else
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing And LCase(Target) = "closed" Or LCase(Target) = "x" Then
    Target.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).Select
End If
End If
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What "it is working fine" should mean? That it runs without raising an error? What "last row with same text" should mean? "closed" or "x" on the column K:K? If everything works as you need, what kind of help do you need from us? To make it paste in a different place than on the last empty row?

Comment: currently when add "closed" or "x", the row move to upper second row, but need "closed" to move after last upper row with column cell "closed" and same for "x" .

Comment: If so, did you test the code I posted? Doesn't it do what you need?

Comment: yes, exactly what I need, appreciate.

Comment: It is good to know that we here, when somebody spends some time to solve our problem and place an answer solving it, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for directing me, and I apologize because I have recently joined stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not answer my clarification question...

Please, test the next code which assumes that you need to cut the row where you write "closed" or "x" (in column K:K) and copy it after the last such existing record ("closed" or "x"):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 Dim rw As Long

 rw = Target.row

 If rw = 2 Then
      'Do nothing
 Else
    Dim rngF As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then
        If LCase(Target) = "closed" Or LCase(Target) = "x" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.EntireRow.Cut
            Set rngF = FindUp(Target.Value, Range("K:K"))
            If rngF Is Nothing Then Application.EnableEvents = True: Exit Sub
            rngF.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlUp
        End If
    End If
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function FindUp(strCrit As String, rng As Range) As Range
 Dim celF As Range
 Set celF = rng.Find(What:=strCrit, After:=rng.cells(1.1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
 If Not celF Is Nothing Then Set FindUp = celF
End Function
```

Comment: There is a small problem that I encountered which is an error when adding ("Closed" or "x") in column for first time. Is there any proposed amendment to the code? thks

Comment: @dola: I do not understand what you say, sorry... When you speak about an error, **you must mention the error description and the code line where it appears**. Theoretically, it shouldn't care if these strings appears, independent of the fact it would be first or second time... If not any `strCrit` exists, the code should deal with that and exits Sub.

Comment: Sorry, you are right; I forget to say that I did some change to move rows up starting from second row instead to last: 
I change xlPrevious to xlNext in function, remove also offset(1) in (rngF.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlUp).
Really, apologize, your previous code is perfect, maybe I did a mistake in change to get rows move from down to upper.